# Question Regarding Elementary Differentiation

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

If f(x) and g(x) are two twice differential functions satisfying the following:

f ' (x) ≤ g ' (x) for all x<1 and f ' (x) ≥ g ' (x) for all x>1 then what conclusion(s) can be drawn?

A) if f(1) ≥ g(1) then f(x) ≥ g(x) for all x

B) if f(1) ≤ g(1) then f(x) ≤ g(x) for all x

C) f(1) ≤ g(1)

D) f(1) ≥ g(1)

Answer (score 1):

$$f'\le g'\iff (f-g)'\le 0\implies f-g\;\;\text{monotonic descending on certain domain}$$

Try to complete from here.

Addition: thus, in $\;(-\infty,1)\;$ we have $\;f-g\;$ mon. descending, and $\;f-g\;$ mon.  ascending on $\;(1,\infty)\;$ . Can you now see why at $\;x=1\;$ the function $\;f-g\;$ has a global minimal point? And from here that

$$(f-g)(x)\ge (f-g)(1)\;,\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb R$$

Comment: f ' (x) ≤ g ' (x) for all x<1 but for x>1 it changes. So, which option should I select?